# How can I combine 2 columns in sql table to search for full names

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> I have a mySQL database with a FirstName and LastName column and presently i have a search query searching for Lastnames, and When the LastNames match they are echoed on screen along with the FirstName from it's row, Now thats great, what i will like to find out is how can a make the query search for FullNames that are typed into the input feild, keep in mind that i do not have a FullName column the full name will be what the user types in, bellow is an example of what I presently have working! Thanks.

```
if(isset($_GET['name'])){   
    $raw_name=$_GET['name'];

    if(preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $raw_name)){        
        $name=$raw_name;        
        include "connect.php";      
        //-query the database table
        $sql="SELECT userId, FirstName, LastName FROM residential2 WHERE FirstName='" . $name   ."'";
        //-run the query against the mysql query function
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        //-count results
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

        echo "<div align=\"center\">" . $numrows . " results found for " . stripslashes($name) . "</div>";

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){         
            $FirstName =$row['FirstName'];
            $LastName=$row['LastName'];
            $userId=$row['userId']; 
            //-display the result of the array
            echo "<ul>\n"; 
            echo "<li>" . "<a href=\"index.php?id=$userId\">" . $LastName . " "  .$FirstName . "   </a></li>\n";
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
    else {      
        echo "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
$sql="SELECT userId, CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS fullname FROM residential2 WHERE FirstName='" . $name   ."'";

<?php
    $fullname = $row['fullname']; 
?>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could explode the search query (full name) on the server side and compare against first and last names from DB

Comment: only if u have the ques properly, u'll see u have answered, and wat he's looking for..

Comment: @xbonez - the problem with splitting the search query into parts and comparing the parts against database fields is when you have people entering names like 'Philip Seymour Hoffman'. Is Seymour going to be in the firstname, or the lastname field?

Comment: @andrewsi: You could send the 0th index of the exploded array as first name, and the last index as last name. Something like `WHERE FirstName LIKE {split[0]} OR LastName LIKE {split[n]}`

Comment: You're assuming that the first name is always going to be the full firstname, though; if Philip Seymour Hoffman considers Seymour as part of his surname, while Tommy Lee Jones considers Lee as part of his firstname, you can't do a simple split.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys this helps, was a bit tricky at first but figured it out thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

**its very very simple !!**

SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE CONCAT( field1, ' ' , filed2 ) like '% $query %'

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$sql="SELECT userId, FirstName, LastName 
            FROM residential2 
            WHERE concat(FirstName, ' ', LastName) like '%$name%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split the full name into first name and last name and then search accordingly. A code snippet for you:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(name),INSTR(REVERSE(name),' ')+1)) AS first_name,
REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(name),1,INSTR(REVERSE(name),' '))) AS last_name
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$frnd_name = trim(preg_replace( "/[ ]+/", " ", $_GET['frnd_search'] ) );
$arr = explode(" ", $frnd_name, 2);

if(!empty($arr[1]))
    $sql_where = "name LIKE '%".$arr[0]."%' AND lastname LIKE '%".$arr[1]."%'";
else
    $sql_where = "name LIKE '%".$arr[0]."%' OR lastname LIKE '%".$arr[0]."%' OR username LIKE '%".$arr[0]."%' OR email LIKE '%".$arr[0]."%'";

$sql = "SELECT name,lastname,username,email FROM user WHERE ".$sql_where;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "".$row['name']." ".$row['lastname']."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT lname, fname FROM TABLE where CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) LIKE '%$fullname%'
```